# Use case and difference between JHipster UML and JDL

Tags: uml, jhipster, dsl, jdl

`JHipster` provides some great tools for generating `JPA` entities and related objects and classes. [The site showcases and describes comparisons](https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-uml/#dropdown-11) between a few of these options:

1. Using a simple questionnaire **entity-subgenerator** (via `jhipster entity`) for generating very basic entities
2. Creating a UML with the [**JHipster-UML** tool](https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-uml/), or a similar UML tool
3. Using a DSL tool called **JHipster-JDL** with some [nice IDE plugins](https://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-ide/) or [**JDL-Studio**](https://start.jhipster.tech/jdl-studio/)

**The Entity Sub-Generator (for beginners)**

I've found that the **entity-subgenerator** is lacking for advanced users and is very limited on what it can do. However, it's great for new `JHipster` or `Java`/`Spring` users to understand what an entity is or how `JHipster` works regarding code generation.

**JHipster-UML or JHipster-JDL (for advanced users)**

That being the case, I'd only be interested in using **JHipster-UML** or **JHipster-JDL** for entity generation. My questions pertain just to those two techniques and when I would use **JHipster-UML** vs. **JHipster-JDL**:

1. What features does one have that the other does not have?
2. **JHipster-JDL** seems to have been created specifically for `JHipster` while **JHipster-UML** seems to use existing UML DSLs. Should I only use a UML tool only if I have some tool or language-familiarity preference?

These items are not clear on the docs on the website, so I'd love some clarification. Would be happy to update the OS docs to clarify this question for others not coming in with a preference for the two and trying to decide what direction to go with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDL is more powerful than JHipster-UML because it has more features that go beyond class modeling like generating all your microservices applications at once from one file and JHipster 6 will add more features to JDL.

I usually recommend newcomers to start with entity sub generator because you don't have to learn a new language, you create few entities and then you use `jhipster export-jdl` to export these entities as JDL. From there you can easily switch to JDL only.